# How to avoid automatic resclaling of image MS Bot builder framework

Tags: c#, image, botframework, attachment, chatbot

Hello I am coding a chatbot and I need to be able to send images in the chat. They are only small icons.
I have tried adapting the code in the "handling attachtments" sample (https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/15.handling-attachments/Bots/AttachmentsBot.cs)

and also this page of the documentation: (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-add-media-attachments?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp)

But it automatically resizes the small icons to fit a bigger frame. I'm not sure why...

See this screenshot that explains the problem:
[image]

This is the actual image : [image] !!

Here is the code I have used:

```
var reply = MessageFactory.Text("This is an inline attachment.");
reply.Attachments = new List<Attachment>() { GetInlineAttachment() };
await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(reply, cancellationToken);
```

```
       private static Attachment GetInlineAttachment()
        {
            var imagePath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"Resources\uc2icon.png");
            var imageData = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(imagePath));

            return new Attachment
            {
                Name = @"Resources\architecture-resize.png",
                ContentType = "image/png",
                ContentUrl = $"data:image/png;base64,{imageData}",
            };
        }
```

I am fairly new to c# and also coding in general, I appreciate any help!! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Adaptive Card Attachment to solve this issue, try the code below :

```
protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{

    var imagePath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"Resources\uc2icon.png");
    var imageData = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(imagePath));
    var url = $"data:image/png;base64,{imageData}";

    var adaptiveJsonString = "{\"$schema\":\"http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json\",\"type\":\"AdaptiveCard\",\"version\":\"1.0\",\"body\":[{\"type\":\"ImageSet\",\"imageSize\":\"auto\",\"images\":[{\"type\":\"Image\",\"url\":\""+ url + "\"}]}]}";

    var adaptiveCardAttachment = new Attachment()
    {
        ContentType = "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
        Content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(adaptiveJsonString),
    };


    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Attachment(adaptiveCardAttachment), cancellationToken);
}
```

Result : 
[image]

For more samples about Adaptive Card for bot , [see here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/07.using-adaptive-cards) . 
Hope it helps and have a nice day .

Comment: Hi @CealClem , glad to know it is helpful for you . It's the happiest thing for me today.  Pls click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in to mark it as an answer so that it will help others who has similar issue and I am glad to answer your further questions , thanks !